# Sql Query get substring

Tags: sql

```
Row values:
Automation > Consumables > Ladle Cup 2 Kg >
i need Output:Automation 
I Need First > inside values

Row values:
Consumables > Automation > Ladle Cup 2 Kg >
i need Output:`enter code here`Consumables 
I Need First > inside values
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using like SQL server, MySQL? Add tag for that...

Comment: Question is not clear please provide the table schema and data in table format for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is always required to tag the DBMS (`MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, `Oracle`, etc..) what you are using ?

IN SQL-Server the `charindex()` function available to get the index of specified characters (`>`).

In similar way you could use `substring()` function to specify the start_position for string with required length of string.

```
SELECT 
        Row_Value,
        substring(<Row_Value>, 1, charindex('>', <Row_Value>)-1) New_Row_Value
FROM table
```

**Result :**

```
Row_Value                                     New_Row_Value           
Automation > Consumables > Ladle Cup 2 Kg >    Automation
Consumables > Automation > Ladle Cup 2 Kg >    Consumables
```